# xpath cant select only one html tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to get some data from a website, but when i use the following code it's return all of the matched elements, i want to return only 1st match! I've tried extract_first but it returned none!

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from gumtree.items import GumtreeItem



class FlatSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "flat"
    allowed_domains = ["gumtree.com"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://www.gumtree.com/flats-for-sale',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        item = GumtreeItem()
        item['title'] = response.xpath('//*[@class="listing-title"][1]/text()').extract()
        return item
```

How to select only one element with xpath selector ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the first element is actually empty - filter out the non-empty values only and use `extract_first()` - works for me:

```
$ scrapy shell "https://www.gumtree.com/flats-for-sale" -s USER_AGENT="Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.113 Safari/537.36"
In [1]: response.xpath('//*[@class="listing-title"][1]/text()[normalize-space(.)]').extract_first().strip()
Out[1]: u'REDUCED to sell! Stunning Hove sea view flat.'
```

Answer (score 0):

Strictly speaking it should be `response.xpath('(//*[@class="listing-title"])[1]/text()')` but if what you want is to grab the title of each ad (to create an item for example) you should probably do this instead:

```
for article in response.xpath('//article[@data-q]'):
     item = GumtreeItem()
     item['title'] = article.css('.listing-title::text').extract_first()
     yield item
```